# Executing destructor for a value class object in Matlab

Tags: matlab, listener, destructor, handle, value-class

I need to control destruction of a value-class object in Matlab.
The problem is as following.

I have a some program (let's call it `MyProg`) that during execution creates a value-class object (lets call it `MyValClass`). `MyValClass` has a handle-class object  as one of its properties (lets call it `MyHandClass`). That handle class initiates some events that `MyProg` listens to.

The problem appears is `MyValClass` object is destroyed (usually it happens on exceptions or user termination). I guess, that because there are still listeners listening to events of `MyHandClass`, the `MyHandClass` object is not destroyed, and remains in memory.

I would like to control the destruction of `MyValClass` object, so that I could implicitly delete its `MyHandClass` property. Is it possible?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be most helpful for us to see a [mcve], in order to know what your classes look like and how you destroy them. Could you please [edit] the question to contain some sample code?

Comment: You can just add a `delete` method to your class, which will automatically be called as part of the cleanup. [Docs reference](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/handle-class-destructors.html). Within this method, you can delete associated objects if you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bit of background on handle vs value classes:

1. Objects of a value class are not "destroyed", and they do not have a destructor method. Think of value classes as behaving like the variable `a` when you've set `a = 1`. `a` is not "destroyed" when you type `clear a`, there's just no variable `a` any more. Value objects are just data, like `1`, and they don't get destroyed.
2. The above is true even if the value class has a method called `delete`. A `delete` method on a value class is just like any other method. It is not a destructor, and it does not get automatically called when the variable is cleared. It only gets called when you explicitly call it.
3. Handle classes always, whether you implement one or not, have a method called `delete`, which is a destructor method (i.e. is called when the object is destroyed). If you don't implement one, they will be given a default method called `delete`, which does nothing other than destroy the object. If you implement a `delete` method, MATLAB will run that when destroying the object. But there is always a `delete` method that is a destructor, even if you don't implement one.

So - to your question - if you wish to control the destruction of `MyValClass`, you must change it to become a handle class. If it's a value class, it is  not destroyed and there's nothing to control.

There are other things you might be able to do instead of directly "controlling the destruction". For example, you create an [`onCleanup`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/oncleanup.html) object. This is a class that does nothing but execute a user-specified function on its destruction (it's a handle class, so it can do this). So if your code exits because of an exception or user termination, the `onCleanup` destructor will execute. You could, for example, put some code in there that would explicitly find references to `MyHandlClass` and deleted them.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. I will try using onCleanup

Answer (score 0):

The destructor for value object may be necessary, for example, if the class is responsible for accessing data from file and you want to close file when your accessor goes out of scope. There are number of reasons why you would not want such class to be a handle class (e.g. weird behavior on array of objects)

Other reason is creating existing objects counter.

My solution is to define hidden property, delete_, and assign `onCleanup(@()something)` object to this property. The function, provided to `onCleanup` would close the files, decrement object counter etc....

Comment: What if the value object is copied? When the first copy is destroyed, your `onCleanup` will be called, and the other copies of the object will not have access to the resources. If the object owns resources, it must be a handle object, if it doesn’t own resources it should be a value object. This is the only distinction between the two types.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. `a=b` for value classes does not work in Matlab as it does not allow to overload `=` operator. 
We had to write custom `copy` operator and inform users that using `a=b` may bring unexpected consequences. It is still better then using handle classes though we have not fully explored the possibilities of `mixing.Copyable`. May be moving to handle classes will be less hustle after all.